# Error while building using colon - colcon build --symlink-install --cmake-args

Tags: autonomous-car, automation

```
shahmeet18@shahmeet18-Precision-5510:~/autoware$ colcon build --symlink-install --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
Starting >>> autoware_lint_common
Starting >>> autoware_auto_geometry_msgs
Starting >>> autoware_auto_mapping_msgs
Starting >>> tier4_debug_msgs
Starting >>> autoware_common_msgs
Starting >>> autoware_auto_system_msgs
Starting >>> autoware_adapi_v1_msgs
Starting >>> tier4_planning_msgs
Finished <<< autoware_lint_common [1.28s]                                                                                                                                                               
Starting >>> autoware_cmake
--- stderr: autoware_auto_geometry_msgs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/humble/share/rosidl_generator_py/cmake/../../../lib/rosidl_generator_py/rosidl_generator_py", line 8, in <module>
    from rosidl_generator_py import generate_py
ImportError: cannot import name 'generate_py' from 'rosidl_generator_py' (/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_generator_py/__init__.py)
gmake[2]: *** [autoware_auto_geometry_msgs__py/CMakeFiles/autoware_auto_geometry_msgs__py.dir/build.make:158: rosidl_generator_py/autoware_auto_geometry_msgs/_autoware_auto_geometry_msgs_s.ep.rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c.c] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:590: autoware_auto_geometry_msgs__py/CMakeFiles/autoware_auto_geometry_msgs__py.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2`
---
Failed   <<< autoware_auto_geometry_msgs [1.33s, exited with code 2]
Aborted  <<< tier4_debug_msgs [1.33s]
Aborted  <<< autoware_common_msgs [1.34s]
Aborted  <<< autoware_cmake [0.08s]
Aborted  <<< autoware_auto_mapping_msgs [1.40s]                                                                                                                                        
Aborted  <<< autoware_auto_system_msgs [1.42s]
Aborted  <<< autoware_adapi_v1_msgs [1.73s]                                                                                    
Aborted  <<< tier4_planning_msgs [1.94s]                                 

Summary: 1 package finished [3.00s]
  1 package failed: autoware_auto_geometry_msgs
  7 packages aborted: autoware_adapi_v1_msgs autoware_auto_mapping_msgs autoware_auto_system_msgs autoware_cmake autoware_common_msgs tier4_debug_msgs tier4_planning_msgs
  7 packages had stderr output: autoware_adapi_v1_msgs autoware_auto_geometry_msgs autoware_auto_mapping_msgs autoware_auto_system_msgs autoware_common_msgs tier4_debug_msgs tier4_planning_msgs
  226 packages not processed
```

How can I rectify this?

Comment: Did you read the log? You need to locate the `generate_py` file

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can happen when there are multiple Python interpreters on a system. I've seen this before with Anaconda users.

Here's an issue filed previously with this exact error: https://github.com/ros2/rosidl_python/issues/168

Note that the `rosidl_generator_py` package is present and installed in `/opt/ros/humble`, but the script is having trouble finding the Python module in the same package.

The debian packages for ROS 2 are built to use the system's default Python 3 interpreter. If you have another interpreter installed on your system (take a look at `which python3`), you should disable it when using ROS 2 debian packages. If you wish to re-build ROS 2 using a different interpreter, please try uninstalling the debians and building all of ROS 2 from source.